# do_upload function not working - codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have configured a code igniter project on IIS. I am facing an issue while uploading an image in user model using upload library. Here is my function.

```
public function upload_image($file,$path, $url) {
        $image = time();
        //////////Remove any Old file with this name///////
        if (file_exists($path . $image))
            unlink($path . $image);
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $config['upload_path'] = $path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg';

        $config['file_name'] = $image;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
            return false;//redirect($url);
            // $this->session->set_flashdata('post', $this->input->post());
            // $this->reload($url, $this->upload->display_errors(), 'danger');
        } else {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            return $upload_data['file_name'];
        }
    }
```

I am calling this function from controller like that

```
$path = 'assets/profileimages/';
$file = 'imagefile';
$imagepath= $this->users->upload_image($file,$path,'Users/addUser');
```

it is giving following error.

```
domainname currently unable to handle this request.
```

In the logs, i have following error.

```
404 Page Not Found: Users/assets
```

Can any one help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. It was due to "extension=php_fileinfo.dll" in php.ini which is not enable. It is requirement for codeigniter 3.1.2.